# What does Java do when we import packages multiple times in the same class?

Tags: java

Try this piece of code. It compiles.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ImportMultipleTimes
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("3 packages imported multiples times in the same class.");
   }
}
```

Does the compiler simply ignore the additional import statements?

Comment: **yes** it will considered redundant by the compiler

Comment: How did you come to wondering this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it will be considered redundant by the compiler, as specified by the [JLS 7.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2-300):

> Two or more type-import-on-demand declarations in the same compilation unit may name the same type or package. All but one of these declarations are considered redundant; the effect is as if that type was imported only once.

Note:

- "type-import-on-demand" is a package import: `import somepackage.*;`
- the same applies [for single-type-import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1-300) : *"If two single-type-import declarations [...] attempt to import [...] the same type, [...] the duplicate declaration is ignored."*